# Bootstrap Carousel Controls Sizing

Tags: css, bootstrap-carousel

How to customize the size of controls in the bootstrap carousel with CSS? Im currently using Bootsrap 4. I have tried  this but this only moves it.

```
.carousel-contol-prev {
    height: 26%;
    top: 33%;    
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
carousel-control-next-icon, .carousel-control-prev-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 100px !important;
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

you can change height and width according to your requirements. one thing carousel controller is image < > not font in bootstrap 4